# NSTimer Will Not Invalidate

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, invalidation

```
-(IBAction) loadWeb: (id) sender {

     [_webView loadRequest:nsrequest2];
     _webView1.hidden = YES;
     _webView.hidden = NO;

     self.checkForAdd = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 
         target:self selector:@selector(checkForAddToCart:) userInfo:nil 
         repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
    [self.checkForAdd invalidate];
}
```

How would I invalidate the `timer`? I have tried it without `self` and many other ways, but for some reason, when I press the button the timer does not invalidate.

Comment: Is the `loadWeb:` method called multiple times? Is `self.checkForAdd` used anywhere else?

Comment: Put an NSLog in loadWeb and in button1, and in button1 log the value of checkForAdd.  Likely you will find that either loadWeb is being called more times than button1 or that button1 is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `loadWeb:` is called multiple times. If it is, you will have old timers running without having a reference to them so you can't invalidate them. You should have `[self.checkForAdd invalidate];` before you create the new timer.

When you do `invalidate` the timer, if you aren't creating a new one, set `self.checkForAdd = nil;` to be sure you aren't going to try using the timer again (some actions will throw an exception if you do).

If at any point you do `self.checkForAdd = nil;` without having `invalidate`d the timer then you won't have a reference to it so you won't be able to `invalidate` it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `loadWeb` is being trigger by a button. So you will be creating new timer every time when button will be press. Its better you create timer on some where else, like create in init, or in viewDidLoad method, because if you are creating this here, you have to make sure you are not creating timer again and again. You can do this by doing a `if` check

```
if(!self.checkForAdd){
self.checkForAdd = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 
         target:self selector:@selector(checkForAddToCart:) userInfo:nil 
         repeats:YES];
}
```

Right now its creating new timer on button tap, and previous one have no reference.